# Cannot write Dataframe result as a Hive table/LFS file

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have encountered an issue while writing the filtered data to a file. There are around 27 files created in local file system but with no output.

Below is the code used:

I'm reading the file as a dataframe

val in_df=spark.read.csv("file:///home/Desktop/Project/inputdata.csv").selectExpr("_c0 as Id","_c1 as name","_c2 as dept")

Then to register this dataframe as a temp table

in_df.registerTempTable("employeeDetails")

Now the requirement is to count the number of employees for each department and store it to a file.

val employeeDeptCount=spark.sql("select dept,count(*) from employeedetails group by dept")

//The following code is writing to Hive default warehouse as n number parquet files.

employeeDeptCount.write.saveAsTable("aggregatedcount")

//The following code is writing to LFS but No Output but n files are created

employeeDeptCount.write.mode("append").csv("file:///home/Desktop/Project")

Answer (score 0):

```
  val in_df=spark.read.csv("file:///home/Desktop/Project/inputdata.csv").selectExpr("_c0 as Id","_c1 as name","_c2 as dept")

  // please, show your result
  in_df.show(false)

  val employeeDeptCount= in_df.groupBy("dept").count().alias("count")
  employeeDeptCount.persist()
  employeeDeptCount.write.format("csv").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("aggregatedcount")
  employeeDeptCount.repartition(1).write.mode("append").csv("file:///home/Desktop/Project")
  employeeDeptCount.unpersist()

// in_df.createOrReplaceTempView()
// in_df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView()
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. But this code still doesn't work. employeeDeptCount.write.mode("append").csv("file:///home/Desktop/Project") creating almost n number of files with no ouput like part-00166-01c28af4-e2c7-4561-8c3c-e0534d571a99.csv

Comment: Here's the output. +------+-----+
|rating|count|
+------+-----+
|1     |6110 |
|3     |27145|
|5     |21201|
|4     |34174|
|2     |11370|
+------+-----+

Comment: "file:///home/Desktop/Project/inputdata.csv" - please, show data with your file. and employeeDeptCount.show(false) - please show result. thx.

Comment: Input data - empid empcourse dept 196 242 3
186 302 3
22 377 1
244 51 2
166 346 1
298 474 4
115 265 2
253 465 5
305 451 3
6 86 3
62 257 2

Comment: aggergated ouput --- deptnum countofemplyees +------+-----+
|dept|count|
+------+-----+
|1     |6110 |
|3     |27145|
|5     |21201|
|4     |34174|
|2     |11370|
+------+-----+

Comment: use .repartition(1) or .coalesce(1)